# Capturing and processing some data on clicking a link on a page using ajax and passing the processed data to new page which the link directs to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link on a page and I would love to do some processing with ajax and pass the results to another page. I want to handle all of this when someone is clicking the link and they are sent to the other page and shown the results of the processed data which i want to add to a div on the new page.  I tried something like this.

```
$('#view_report').click( function () {        
    //Some logic to pick data on this page called index.
    //Send the data via an ajax call
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "/cycles/wizard/0",
        data :"sample data,
        dataType : "html",
        success : function(response) {               
           //load the data in a div with the class report on the new  page called report
            $('.report').load("/cycles/report",response, function(){

                console.log("worked");
            });
        }
    });

    return false;
} );
```

I have a link on my index page like so

```
<a id="view_report" href="/cycles/report">View Report</a>
```

However when I click the link it doesn't work and if I remove the id it works fine moving to the report page. How can I achieve this?

Comment: the `success` callback is called on the successful ajax-call on the current page, not on the page a user goes to

Comment: @skip405 what should I do then?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the href triggered before your click handler.
You can try to remove the 'href' from  and after console.log(..) add the line:

```
window.location.href = "<your domain>/cycles/report";
```

Comment: from the html code. it can be only: <a id="view_report">

Comment: or <a id="view_report" style="cursor: pointer;"> to keep the mouse pointer on hover

Comment: can you add 'response' content?

Comment: I just edited the link to highlight why I cant remove the href

Comment: What do you mean by 'i cant remove the href'?

Comment: Anyway I tried removing it and applying your solution and it didn't work.

Comment: and do you get your console.log message?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72220/discussion-between-wasswa-samuel-and-itayb).

Answer (score 0):

you should close double inverted comma in ajax data parameter.

replace

```
data :"sample data,
```

with

```
data :"sample data",
```

also remove href attribute from your link.

```
<a id="view_report">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [Web Storage](http://Web%20Storage%20API) for this (either `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` if it needs to be cleared if browser is closed). I would store a JSON string with the needed data when a user clicks a link.

```
$('#view_report').on('click', function(e){
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent the default behaviour
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "/cycles/wizard/0",
        data : "sample data",
        dataType : "html", //I guess it needs changing so that you send only data to the client, not html
        success : function(response) {               
           var data = JSON.stringify(response); //JSON representation of your data here if not in JSON

           //session storage example here, localStorage is the same
           sessionStorage.setItem('dataAfterClicking', data);

           //after saving the data - go to the clicked page
           window.location.href = link;
        }
    });

});
```

Then on the needed page I would check if we have anything stored.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = sessionStorage.getItem('dataAfterClicking');

    if( data ) {
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);

        //do something with the parsedData here, like making a div with it
    }
});
```

Comment: This is more of a proof of concept, not the actual solution. So the real data needs tweaking for it to work. Hope the idea is clear

Comment: Am not sure about the JSON . The response I get from the ajax call is in the final format. Its not really data but data properly formatted with html and just needs to be placed in a div on the new page but I get the idea.

Comment: Maybe you could change the server-side code :) and construct the needed html yourself. Anyways, I don't know any other ways to share data between pages